# Equivalent of Initialize/Dispose in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

**ASP.Net MVC3**

In my base controllers I use `Initialize`/`Dispose` methods to create/dispose my ADO.NET connection.

**WCF**

Can I something similar in WCF? I'm using my own `ServiceHostFactory` and it would be nice if it's possible using it or the custom `ServiceHost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Please post if there are a better one.

a) Implement `IDispatchMessageInspector` in class:

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // creates a new database connection
        return SessionFactory.Create();
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // closes the connection
        var session = (Session) correlationState;
        if (session != null)
            session.Dispose();
    }
```

b) Add it using web.config or programatically in the `ServiceHost`:

```
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher chDisp in ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDisp in chDisp.Endpoints)
            {
                epDisp.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(myMessageInspector);
            }
        }
```